# Jacobi triple product for multidimensional lattices

Tags: special-functions, gm.general-mathematics

The Jacobi triple product identity gives as a special case a product formula for the theta function of a 1-dimensional lattice. Is there a more general product formula for the theta function of an arbitrary lattice?

Comment: Have you heard of MacDonald identities?

Comment: I know a little bit about them, but it's not clear to me whether I get a formula for the theta function of an arbitrary lattice from them. For one, I don't see a way of associating an affine root system to an arbitrary lattice.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid point.  I think I spoke too soon.  You can get product formulas for theta functions of a more general class of positive definite lattices using a Borcherds-Harvey-Moore lift of a suitable weight 1/2 weakly holomorphic modular form (i.e., with a pole at a cusp).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Borcherds-Harvey-Moore lift; is there any particular introduction to it you would recommend? Also, do you know which positive-definite lattices this gives a formula for?

Comment: I don't know a good reference, but a search for "Borcherds products" should yield something fruitful.